# A Faster Ranking For Most Common First Name In MYSQL

Tags: mysql, group-by, ranking, rank

I wanted to query my large MYSQL database of users to find the most common first names and to rank them. I also wanted to be able to display a current user's first name rank. I came up with a solution, but it seems a little slow. I was wondering if there was a faster way to do this.

Here is the query I came up with.

```
SELECT rank,fname
   FROM (SELECT @rownum:=@rownum+1 rank,fname 
      FROM (SELECT fname,count(*) 
      FROM userlist GROUP BY fname 
      ORDER BY count(*) DESC) AS R1 
   JOIN (SELECT @rownum:=0) AS I) AS R2  
WHERE fname = 'Username'
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In order to get ranking of a specific name try in this way

```
select count(*) + 1 as rank from 
    (select count(*) as number from userlist group by fname having number > 
       (select count(*) as number from userlist where fname='Username') order by number desc) as tab;
```

edit. If you want to show even the name add a user variable:

```
set @name = 'nick';
select @name as fname,count(*) + 1 as rank from 
    (select count(*) as number from userlist group by fname having number > 
       (select count(*) as number from userlist where fname=@name) order by number desc) as tab;
```

Comment: That works perfect. It's 23% quicker the first time it is ran, and it only takes .0001 seconds the second time it is run (with the same name). Thanks